# ip addresses/domain names are geographical bound?

Tags: domain, ip, internet

i wonder if ips are bound to specific geolocations?

lets say that i've got this ip 111.111.111.111 from my ISP to my home computer in France.

is it possible for me to use this ip in Norway?

and the same goes with domain names.

if iv'e got a domain name like mydomain.de, does it mean that my computer has to be in Germany or could it be located in Denmark?

cause i always wonder where the actual server is located every time a website got different top level domains, eg google.dk, google.fr, google.de and so on.

are they located in same country as the top domain or doesnt it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason IP addresses seem geographically bound is that the subnet they're part of is handled by a router in a specific part of the world. You could theoretically use it somewhere else, but you'd need to run a connection (either a physical line or a VPN) from the router to the endpoint, but it would be either expensive or slow.

There is no technical reason why a country TLD must be associated with an address located in said country. DNS does not care what address is associated with a hostname, only that one exists.

Answer (score 1):

The public IP is reserved to your ISP. If you change of ISp, you will change your IP too. This is due to the fact that the ISP buy a range of IP and announe it to the Internet's routers.

The DNS can be set to the IP you want. The name you put in it, can be localized (like in google.dk) but the IP can be where you want in the world. The DNS just put a resolution between name and IP, and don't proves that your IP is in Denemark.

Answer (score 1):

For IPs, the location where one is used can change, though it is a bit more complicated and you can use Google to find out about the ins and outs of how IP allocations work.

For domains, the TLD (.de, .com) does not make it so it can only be hosted in a certain country.

Google is a very special case actually. Searching for something on google.fr and google.dk can give you different results, even if it is the same query, as they will prioritize local websites ".fr" or ".dk" ones when it comes to results. The servers themselves are not necessarily hosted in corresponding countries, the TLDs mostly being used for localization purposes by Google.

Comment: so when i use online tools like: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/ to check the route of a packet, what are the location jumps? where the company that owns it is located? cause i dont think it could be where the computer actually is located cause if i type in my IP it doesnt show the city im in.